# progress bar remains empty using asynctask - EDIT - dialog never stops loading

Tags: android

I want to have a progress bar while waiting for GPS signal to establish.

I use:

```
public class GetGPSData extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {
               @Override
               protected void onPreExecute() {
                   //super.onPreExecute();
                   myprogressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                   myprogressBar.setProgress(0);

               }

               @Override
               protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
                   //super.onProgressUpdate(progress);
                   myprogressBar.setProgress(progress[0]);

               }

               @Override
               protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

               latitude = gps.getLatitude();
               longitude = gps.getLongitude();

               while (latitude == 0 || longitude ==0)
               {

                   try {
                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }  
               }
                return null;
               }

                  protected void onCancelled() {
                      Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Error connecting", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                  }

               @Override
               protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                   super.onPostExecute(result);
                   myprogressBar.setProgress(100);

               Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Your Location is  \nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

               }
           }
```

and:

```
 <ProgressBar android:id="@+id/myprogressBar"
  style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal" 
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
  android:indeterminate="true"
  android:layout_below="@+id/comments"
  android:padding="5dp" />
```

But the progress bar remains empty.

Also,when I click the button in order to start getting the GPS signal, the GPS flashes ,then stop flashing ( but in the meanwhile it still searches for signal ) and when I press it again it gives me the Toast message I have in onPostExecute.Is this normal behavior?

Shouldn't the icon be flashing until finds the signal and then show me the message without the user having to press again the button?

--------------------------------UPDATE----------------------------------------------------

I also tried with ProgressDialog :

```
public class GetGPSData extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {
               ProgressDialog progressDialog = null;               

               @Override
               protected void onPreExecute() {
                  super.onPreExecute();



                   progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(ShowList.this);
                   progressDialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                            GetGPSData.this.cancel(true);
                        }

                    });
                   progressDialog.setMessage("Waiting for location...");
                   progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
                   progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
                   progressDialog.show();


               }

               @Override
               protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
                   super.onProgressUpdate(progress);


               }

               @Override
               protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

                   latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                   longitude = gps.getLongitude();


              while  (latitude == 0 || longitude == 0)
               {
                   try {               
                    Thread.sleep(1000);     

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }  

               }


                return null;
               }

                  protected void onCancelled() {
                      Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Cancelled/Error connecting", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                      progressDialog.dismiss();
                  }

               @Override
               protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

                   progressDialog.dismiss();

 Toast.makeText(ShowList.this, "Your Location is  \nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

               }
           }
```

but now  the progress dialog never stops loading.If I press back button and then again the button to get location ,then it gives me the toast message (with location).

-------------------SOLUTION------------------------------

The problem was (after correcting the while loop) that you must put this.location=location

```
 public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        this.location=location;
    }
```

Comment: use publishProgress() inside doinBackground ../

Comment: @blackbelt:When I press the button to start getting position,the dialog progress is show but it is never stopping.It doesn't stop loading.I must press the back button in order to stop and then again the button to get position and then it gives me the toast message with position.The problem is that it must stop loading and show me the toast.(I am using the UPDATE code above).

Comment: it means that the onPostExecuted is never called. It is never called because the doInBackground never ends

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the onPostExecute callback is invoked when the doInBackground callback runs to end. If it is not called it means that

```
 while  (latitude == 0 || longitude == 0) {
        try {               
                Thread.sleep(1000);     

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }  

       latitude = gps.getLatitude();
       longitude = gps.getLongitude();

  }

 Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "out the while");
```

neither `latitude` or `longitude` value is `!= 0;`

Also if your `while` loop never ends you will leak your `AsyncTask`

Comment: :latitude and longitude are 0 (initialized).The onPostExecute is "executed" the second time i press the button.

Comment: :I didn't understand your comment (the previous).As long as the coordinates are 0 then sleep.If you get them ,execute onpostexexute

Comment: that's exactly what's happening. The coordinates can be never != 0

Comment: can you put a Log has last line of your doInBackground and see if it is pritented on logcat?

Comment: stupid question maybe you have more than a dialog at screen?'

Comment: :A log where?To longitude = gps.getLongitude(); ? To return null?But log takes (String,String) ,what should I put?Sorry I am not experienced

Comment: :No , I have only this dialog

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30400/discussion-between-blackbelt-and-george)

Answer (score 3):

Use [publishProgress](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#publishProgress%28Progress...%29) in your `doInBackground` method

But in your case, you shouldn't use a horizontal `ProgressBar` with value because you couldn't know when your longitude and latitude are known, just use a simple `ProgressBar`.

Comment: :And any ideas about how to implemented in my code because I am no t familiar with this? Also , what about my other question?Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your Progress bar is empty because you didn't call **publishProgress()** method inside doInBackground() method.
publishProgress call onProgressUpdate() method inside your asynctask.

Comment: :And any ideas about how to implemented in my code because I am no t familiar with this? Also , what about my other question?Thanks!

Comment: How do you catch the GPS signal? Do you use locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE); with a LocationListener ?

Comment: :I press a button and:gps = new GPSTracker(ShowList.this);.Where GPSTracker is a Service and finds the signal.Then, after gps = new GPSTracker(ShowList.this); I execute the asynctask.

Comment: Ok let me see, maybe I can help you. Hovertheless there is a good tutorial for tracking latitude and longitude:http://www.tutos-android.com/geolocalisation-android , and you have have source code here: http://www.tutos-android.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/LocalisationExemple.zip

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30049/discussion-between-george-and-jarvis)

Comment: now I can't, maybe, tomorrow in the morning (I live in France)

Answer (score 1):

The reason your progress isn't being published is because you're not calling [`publishProgress()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#publishProgress%28Progress...%29) in your `doInBackground` function.  Also, the reason that your GPS icon stops flashing is because you have a GPS signal.  The reason your app says it's still searching for a GPS signal is because your while loop conditions are never updated so your loop never ends.  The toast shows up when you press the button again though because a second `AsyncTask` is being started and it's completing right away.

To fix all of this, you would want to update your `doInBackground` function to look something like this:

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

    do {
        latitude = gps.getLatitude();
        longitude = gps.getLongitude();

        /* Not needed for an indeterminate progress bar */
        publishProgress(0);

        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch(InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } while  (latitude == 0 || longitude == 0);

    return null;
}
```

This will continually look for a gps fix and will break out of the loop properly when a fix is achieved.  It will also call your `onProgressUpdate` to update your progress.  The only caveat here is that you need to determine for yourself what you're going to use as progress.  I have it in here as just being 0 so you can see where to call it but without knowing what you're using to measure progress, I can't definitively say what will work best for you.

In your case, an indeterminate progress bar might be better than one with a min/max.  I see you've done that in your `ProgressDialog` example so I would just remove the `publishProgress` line in the above code and go with your second example.

Comment: :Unfortunately , still the same.The dialog remains "loading".It doesn't stop..(I use progressdialog ,so i don't have an xml progressbar)

Comment: What version of Android are you using?

Comment: :I have minSdkVersion="4" and target "17".

Comment: What version are you actually running the app on?

Comment: Nevermind then. I was thinking it might be a threading issue with AsyncTasks not executing in a thread pool but Android didn't move back to serial thread pools until 3.0 I believe.  I'd have to see more of your code to know why it isn't working.  I'd remove any old code from your question and update it with all the relevant newer code you have.

Comment: :Just check the update.This is the code I use.And I don't need xml anymore because i use progressdialog now.If you want to go to chat tell me please.Thanks

Comment: :thanks for your help.the problem was with onLocationChanged. (i upvoted though)